# Display with mapBox offline raster from my website

Tags: android, mapbox, raster, osmdroid, tile

I'm looking for a library to display a raster, host on my website, on an Android device.

I'm trying to do that with MapBox but I just read that:

> At this time, the offline database format is private. In the future, we may publicly document the format and implement Mapbox Mobile APIs for consuming pre-built databases.

Does it mean I can only display the raster online?
Is there anyway to just point tiles' source to a internal folder?

Should I use OSMDroid instead of MapBox?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `4.2.0-beta.5` of our SDK and work off [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/AddWmsSourceActivity.java) to add a raster layer from a web map service. I'm not sure what you mean by offline when you are requesting to add a web map hosted on your website.

Comment: I want to download all raster's tiles from my server and be able to display them offline with the current device position add on the map. The satellite map in background isn't important